# Calculating reactors for parallel connection of thyristors (SCRs)

Tags: inductor, parallel, thyristor, scr

I have been looking for more information on how to connect two thyristors in parallel in order to balance the load. From what I have found there are two options: either using balancing resistors, which is inefficient, or using reactors (inductors in series with the thyristor).

So far, everything is clear to me. However, I can't find any information on how to calculate the inductance required for each inductor. Since both thyristors are identical, the unbalanced current shouldn't be that high, therefore the inductance shouldn't be that high either (compared to a parallel connection of two different thyristors). I also assume that both inductors would have the same spec, since both thyristors are identical.

Also, can two separated inductors be used as reactors? Or do those two inductors have to be on the same common core?

Let's say I have two thyristors of 220 V and 1 A and the desired output is 1.5 A. How do I calculate the values for these inductors?

Here's a schematic of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Thyristors in parallel]

Comment: Do you really need to parallel SCRs? Very large SCRs are available, I used 1800 amp SCRs 40 years ago.

Comment: @Mattman944 preferably, yes. There are two reasons behind it. Heat dissipation and stock availability.

Comment: @Mattman944 For the context: The SCRs will be used in an AC motor controller. Therefore the SCRs will be either SMT or THT in order to get a small design.

Comment: How little? Having to parallel SMT thyristors sounds like a thermal management problem more than one of total current ratings.

Comment: Surely you would use a single CT inductor .To make the question get better answers why dont you state the turn on time of your SCRs

Comment: If you mount _either_ SMD or THT, you aren’t paralleling them.

Comment: @Autistic turn on time varies based on user's preference for RPM.

Comment: winny what do you mean? I am paralleling them.

Comment: @Tim Williams enough not to need a heatsink and let the copper plane of the PCB to get rid of the heat. Therefore spreading the load across multiple SCRs would also spread the heat source.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, can two separated inductors be used as reactors? Or do those two inductors have to be on the same common core?

Balancing was done (in my youngest time ...) with ... transformer.
So coupling your two inductors would be "enough".
Inductors used alone would limit di/dt.

Here is a simulation showing the need of "balancing" currents.
Note that this can be done only with TWO SCRs.
If you use 4 SCRs paralleled, this must be done with 3 transformers.

**First** simulation, when **no balancing** is used ... Just an anodic resistance of 1 Ohm difference.
The currents are **"very" different**.

[image]

**Second** simulation, **adding a "transformer"** in the "anodic" circuit.
Are you convinced? The currents are now **quasi equal**.

[image]

NB: the big SCR uses a "bunch" of little SCR paralleled ...
No balancing is needed ... because there are on the **same "die"**,
and/or specifications are selected **very "nearest"**.
And wiring of these PCBs is a very special kind of "wiring" ...

Evaluation of "inductors/transformer" for "reasonable" result.

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrtvn5vd8vr41se/current%20sharing%20inductive%20v100.cir?dl=0) to file made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).

Example. See the inductor's value and "sharing" fraction.

[image]

[image]

One could make LL bigger ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, main question was how do I calculate the minimum inductance required for those two inductors?

Comment: Note that L1 & L2 is ... a transformer, and some mH would be enough. Just passing a large current. Note that sense of coupling is very important.

Comment: is there a way to calculate the inductance for that? What's the optimal mH required?

Comment: I don't have notes for now, but this could help ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hwnGHOe9f8

Comment: I add also the file (interactive) in answer for simulation "evaluating" ...

Answer (score 0):

> Since both thyristors are identical, the unbalanced current shouldn't be that high

Your assumption -- but they aren't matched in any meaningful way, as far as I know.  (Maybe they can be special ordered that way?)

Normally, diode junctions (SCRs are about two in series, when on) vary by some 10s of mV between individuals of given type, at same current and temperature.  10s of mV additionally for differences in temperature.  And that gives, well, you'll want to refer to the V<sub>TM</sub> curve or dynamic resistance figure to see how much voltage mismatch translates to what current mismatch.  Needless to say, a, say, 10% voltage mismatch, will result in *much more than* a 10% current mismatch.

The inductors serve two purposes:

1. Provides some voltage drop to ballast (i.e., dominate over) the difference in V<sub>TM</sub>
2. Somewhat isolates the transient event as they turn on (i.e., one can potentially turn on, say, some 100s ns before the other, and both still see similar turn-on conditions.)

(Hm, I don't actually know offhand whether this matters. Is SCR turn-on effectively independent of V<sub>A</sub>?  I would expect it's at least slower near V<sub>TM</sub>.)

Somewhat as a corollary, inductance also limits dI/dt, which may be needed with some sources/loads.  (Likewise a snubber may be needed to absorb the energy stored in the inductor during reverse recovery.)

Ballasting behaves same as paralleling any other diodes, so, a fraction of a volt should be sufficient.  Even a couple volts might be acceptable, as an inductor is non-dissipative at AC (assuming these SCRs will be used in anti-parallel pairs as a TRIAC, or that you're actually using TRIACs as such).

Strictly speaking, the inductors can be coupled, by using a center-tapped winding with the load connected to the tap and the two SCRs at either end (in RF, this is known as a 0° power combiner).  But this will not limit dI/dt once both turn on, and the coupling may cause hazardous voltage in the instant before both have turned on.  Best to use independent inductors, then.

At 50Hz and 1A, 1V drop is afforded from 1Ω reactance, or 3.2mH.

Given the reference to SMT components, the cure [large, expensive inductors] sounds much worse than the disease.  If your problem is thermal, consider a MOS type SSR: the resistive characteristic can have much lower voltage drop.  It will be more expensive than SCRs (but probably still cheaper than the inductors, hah).

I have no idea about availability issues; without location and budget given, I'm assuming what is typical for me and most readers, i.e., western markets.

Comment: the SCRs will be used in parallel and in the same direction, so it won't be like a triac configuration. The load is a 160V DC uniploar stepper motor. Hence why I attached the image to the question. That's exactly what I want to accomplish. I split across the two SCRs.

Comment: About MOS type SSRs, would they be able to switch on and off in 1mS, and also switch off at the 0 AC crossing?

Comment: @SumutiuMarius Do you know they'll turn off at the zero crossing? Given motor inductance and all?

Comment: the SCRs would be turned on by a PWM signal from the microcontroller and let run till they turn off automatically when the AC goes into negative.

Comment: @SumutiuMarius But you said DC... would there not be a rectifier? Wait, are you just doing this half-wave?!

Comment: this is going off topic to the question however, to answer your question, two pair of SCRs in parallel will be used in a bridge rectifier setup, esentially being 8 SCRs in total.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the delay in dA/dT can be solved with capacitors. Same reason why capacitors are used for motors, to bring the current peak to be at the same time with the voltage peak. But I am not sure how exactly is the inductance calculated for the inductance required for these inductors.

So far, there are quite a few cheap toroidal inductors that can be used but not sure if the inductance is "enough".

Answer (score 0):

So, after doing some digging through my physics books, I think I found the answer.

We start with the general formula for voltage at the terminals of an ideal inductor:

$$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}$$

From this, we can say that L is:

$$L=\frac{V}{\frac{dI}{dt}}$$

We know that V<sub>RMS</sub> is:

$$V_{RMS}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot V$$

Since we know that the SCRs won't conduct electricity at the same time for a brief period of time, the intensity through a single SCR is the total intensity of the parallel pair (in my case, 10A). We also know that the SCR will only conduct electricity on the positive side of the sine wave. Therefore V<sub>RMS</sub> is:

$$V_{RMS}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{V_{peak}}{2}$$

So, our V<sub>RMS</sub> is 125 V. Our frequency is 50 Hz, and that is one cycle in 0.02 s. Knowing this, we can calculate the total inductance for the parallel pair of SCRs:

$$L=\frac{125}{\frac{10}{0.02}}$$

From this, we calculate that L is 0.25 H. Also, we use two inductors for our pair of two SCRs, therefore we divide the inductance by the number of inductors coupled, resulting that both inductors need to be L = 0.125 H and 10 A.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Maybe I have misunderstood something.

Comment: You've mixed up formulas; in the first, V and I are time-domain signals \$v(t)\$ and \$i(t)\$. Capitals are usually used to denote either frequency-domain values, or peak or average or other reference values -- constants, not functions.  But often they are still used (for convenience or shorthand) to refer to functions (I'm guilty of this myself..). It is clear from the derivative that these are functions; the expression isn't meaningful otherwise. But then there is no meaning of the Vrms expression, if the same V is meant. This is an AC sinusoidal steady-state relationship.

Comment: Finally, your calculated L invokes cycle time... arbitrarily? And is apparently calculated for handling the full voltage drop, which doesn't sound like it's intended by the application. For reference, the AC S-S relation is \$X_L = 2 \pi F L\$, for frequency in Hz, L in H, and \$X_L\$ in Ω.

Comment: One cycle for AC is done in 0.02s (50 cycles per second -> 50Hz -> 1 cycle/0.02s), and that's our dT.

Comment: I'm not sure the expression has been understood correctly: "dt" isn't a finite difference in time. It's an infinitesimal, and the "d[..]/dt" expression is a calculus operator, meaning, take the slope of the function. The slope of a sine wave is non-constant -- a single number cannot be assigned to it -- it's another function.

Comment: In your formula: XL=2πFL, we have two values we don't know. We don't know the inductance we need. We also don't know what XL this inductor will have since we don't know what inductance we need.

Comment: As said before, a drop of a volt or so is enough to dominate over the fractional-volt differences between SCRs. Do that at rated current, and that's your impedance, and thus, more or less, reactance.

Comment: So, if we assume that 1V is the voltage drop, our impedance is 0.1Ohm (1V at 10A), therefore L is 318uH. Does this inductance split in half (since there are two inductors in series (between the SCRs output)? Therefore both inductors need to be at 160uH?

Comment: They're 320uH each.

Comment: If so, would this: **SC-06-10J-B** work? (P/N is from Digikey)

Comment: No, you need single inductors, with saturation at least equal to peak current, so, 14A or so I guess.

Comment: Is it peak current per SCR or the peak current for both parallel SCRs? If 10A is the desired output, one SCR will handle 5A.

Comment: Also, I could connect both coils for **SC-06-10J-B** in series, thus making it a single inductor. Then using two of the above inductor.

Comment: Peak per inductor... You can't connect those in series, typical CMCs saturate at 10s mA.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out on the right track. I have taken a look and found **MCAP115018062A-381MU** from Farnell.